# nullPointer Exception with my validator Form

Tags: java, struts, validation

hello i have a class Form where i implement the validator like this

```
public class LoginForm extends ActionForm {
    private String login;
    private String password;
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public string getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public string getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,HttpServletRequest request) {
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
        if ( login==null || login.lenght()<=8) {
            errors.add("error",new ActionMessage ("error.login"));
        }
        if ( password==null || password.lenght()<=8) {
            errors.add("error",new ActionMessage ("error.password"));
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

the problem is i have a nullPointerException in this line

```
errors.add("error",new ActionMessage ("error.login"));
```

StackTrace:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Rapport d'exception

message 

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne () qui l'a empèché de satisfaire la requête.

exception 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fr.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.forms.LoginForm.validate(AdministrationSaisieTarifsForm.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processValidate(RequestProcessor.java:950)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:106)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:229)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.invoke(StandardContext.java:2460)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorDispatcherValve.invoke(ErrorDispatcherValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:157)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
```

Comment: it shouldn't even compile properly.
it ought to be "login.length()" not "login.lenght"

Comment: Can you, please, provide the full stack trace?
Does error.login exists in resources?

Comment: Can you tell us the real file/line number reported at the top of the trace, or show us the file AdministrationSaisieTarifsForm.java.

Answer (score 1):

The exception reported by the stack you provided is not in the class/line you mentioned but in the following line:

**fr.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.forms.AdministrationSaisieTarifsForm.validate(AdministrationSaisieTarifsForm.java:77)**

Have a look at the `AdministrationSaisieTarifsForm.validate(...)`, the problem is there according to the stack you provided.

Comment: no just a mistake copy / paste 
the error is in the class i mentionned

Comment: If you tell us what the real file name and line number reported by the stack trace is, and tell us which line in the file you provided corresponds to it, then we can work out what the error is. And probably so can you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to open an other answer according to your update of the stack trace.

The following line

```
errors.add("error",new ActionMessage ("error.login"));
```

can cause a NullPointerException only if the errors variable is null or in the code you pasted this variable is initialized just before by:

```
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
```

Thus, the line number 77 is not the one you think it is. It can't be this one.